# How to get Add/Remove Programs - "Support Information" for a program programatically

Tags: c#, windows

I'm writing a program and I need to get the version number and publisher programatically. If I go into add/remove programs and select a program I can then click on "Click here for support information" (most programs honour it) and it will then bring up a version number and a publisher for the selected program.

I am currently getting the list of program names via the registry key SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall which works well but am stuck on how to get version numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most applications have a string value called "DisplayVersion" under their key in the location you specified.

Answer (score 0):

The DisplayVersion string inside each Uninstall entry (that has one) should be useful.  Unfortunately, it's not guaranteed to be there.